# C# Thread ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, listview

I'm a fairly new to .net and I'm still struggling to understand a lot things, and right now I'm trying to accomplish something relatively simple but I've failed every single time, I would like to add a Thread to my program, this Thread would be responsible to perform the Upload operations to a web server and keep my program responsive providing the feedback of the operations to my users by updating a ListView, where the users would see all the status of the file uploads.

I don't know how to put this Thread inside the program to make it responsive, I couldn't find any examples so far and I'm trying to find a little sample to show me the use of Thread and WinForms in action.

Comment: Threading is available in the System.Threading namespace. Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(someObj.Method)); thread.Start(); Here's a link to help. <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx>

Comment: Creating a new thread isn't the hard part, it's dealing with the UI interactions so that the long running non-UI tasks are in a background thread while the UI tasks are in the UI thread.  Its further complicated when you have periodic updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll want to use is a `BackgroundWorker`.  It's specifically designed for exactly this purpose.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bgw.DoWork += (_, args) => LongRunningTask(bgw);
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw.ProgressChanged += (_, args) =>
    {
        textbox1.Text = args.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void LongRunningTask(BackgroundWorker bgw)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);//placeholder for real work
        bgw.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff when completed.
}
```

A key point to note is that the `DoWork` event runs in a background thread, but the other events all run in the UI thread.  The `BackgroundWorkder` class takes care of ensuring that all on its own.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker`s are great for most threading stuff. Definitely avoid messing around with your own threads if you can. :)

Comment: @Chris They're designed for working with background tasks that need to interact with a UI, either through reporting progress or when the task completes.  If you aren't dealing with a UI then you really shouldn't be using a BGW, it adds unneeded overhead.  `Task` is best in my mind, if you have 4.0+, but using a thread directly for a single long running task with no UI interaction isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Very true servy. I think the majority of stuff I have done where I needed to worry about threads was UI based which is probably where I am coming from. I really should look at Tasks though for when I need them. :)